# Do chained powershell replace commands execute one after the other?

Tags: powershell, replace

This would likely be a non-issue with expert regex comprehension. And only matters because I am running multiple chained replace commands that affect some of the same text in a text file. I also imagine partitioning the txt files based on how delimiter words --that are requiring multiple replaces-- are used, before replace, would help. With that said basic structural knowledge of powershell is useful and I have not found many great resources (open to suggestions!).

The question: Do chained powershell replace commands execute one after the other?

```
 -replace "hello:","hello " `
 -replace "hello ","hello:"
 } | out-file ...
```

Would this silly example above yield hello:'s where there were initially hello:'s?

From working through some projects I gather that the above works most of the time. Yet there always seem to be some edge cases. Is this another aspect of the script or is the order that chained commands (decent number of them) execute in never variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there are operators, not commands.

I say that not to be pedantic, but because "command" has a specific meaning in PowerShell (it is a general name encompassing functions, cmdlets, aliases, applications, filters, configurations (this is a DSC construct), workflows, and scripts), and because the way they can be used together is different.

Most operators are reserved words that begin with `-` (but other things count as operators, like casting), and you can indeed use them chained together. <s>They also execute in order.</s>

I need to clarify; they don't necessarily execute in the order given when you *mix* operators. Multiple of the same operator will because they all have the same precedence, but you should check [about_Operator_Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence?view=powershell-6) to see the order that will be used when you combine them.

Note that some operators can "short-circuit" (which may sound like a malfunction, but it isn't), that is the result of certain boolean operators will not evaluate later operations if the boolean result can not change.

For example:

```
$true -or $false
```

In this example, the `$false` part of the expression will never actually be evaluated. This is important if the next part of the expression is complex or even invalid. Consider these:

```
$true -or $(throw)
$false -or $(throw)
```

The first will return `$true` because (presumably) nothing in the coming expression could make it `$false`.

The second line must evaluate the second expression, and in doing so it `throw`s an exception, halting the program.

So, aside from that aside, yes, you can continue to chain your operators. You also don't need a line continuation character (backtick `` ` ``) at the end of the line if the operator itself is at the end. More useful with boolean operators:

```
$a -and
$b -or
$c -xor
$false
```

A little awkward with something like replace:

```
'apple' -replace
'p',
'z'
```

Regarding this:

> And only matters because I am running multiple chained replace
>   commands that affect some of the same text in a text file.

These operators aren't touching anything in a file, they are working with data in memory, as literals or variables in your script (what you do with it then, like writing to a file is your business).

Further, even then it doesn't change any values already in variables, it returns new ones, which you may assign to a variable or use in any other way.

```
$var = 'apple'
$var -replace 'p','Z'
$var
```

The value of the replacement will be returned, but nothing was done with it so it went out to the console. Then you can see that `$var` was not modified at all, as opposed to:

```
$var = 'apple'
$var = $var -replace 'p','Z'
$var
```

Where the value of `$var` was overwritten.

If there are edge cases, it's likely to be a misunderstanding of something in the sequence of events (an incorrect regular expression, not assigning or using a value, incorrect logic, etc.), as the order of operations will be consistent. If you have any such edge cases, please post them!

Comment: Thank you! Very informative. Did not know to search for operator precedence but that and your answer were precisely the info I was looking for.